# How to add vmArgs for Fontawesmome library in VScode

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, javafx, font-awesome

I am working on a javafx project using VScode and scene builder, and I used the fontawesome-8.2.jar to add an icon. When I try to run the code it gives me an error and if I remove the fontawesome icon it works just fine.
I think the problem is that I need to add the fontawesome in the config but I don't know how.

This is my configuration:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "CafeShopManagmentSystem",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "CafeShopManagmentSystem",
            "projectName": "CafeShopManagementSystem_4876995e",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/java/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        }
        
    ]
}
```

I tried to add the fontawsome in the config like this but it didn't work:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "CafeShopManagmentSystem",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "CafeShopManagmentSystem",
            "projectName": "CafeShopManagementSystem_4876995e",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/java/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,**fontawesome-8.2"**
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        }
        
    ]
}
```

And FYI the fontawesome library is in the same folde as javafx libararies.

Comment: Does not answer your question, but I recommend https://kordamp.org/ikonli/. They have the fontawesome icons.

Comment: I think fontawesome 8.2 is obsolete and does not work with modern JavaFX versions (I could be wrong though - I haven't tried using that library in a long time).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following configuration：

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "CafeShopManagmentSystem",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "CafeShopManagmentSystem",
            "projectName": "CafeShopManagementSystem_4876995e",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/java/lib;C:/path/to/fontawesome-8.2.jar\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",
            "classPaths": ["C:/path/to/fontawesome-8.2.jar"]
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        }
    ]
}
```

*Make sure to replace `C:/path/to/fontawesome-8.2.jar` with the actual path to the FontAwesome JAR file. Also, make sure that the FontAwesome JAR file is in the correct location.*

Comment: I tried and now it gives me this error:

Error: Could not find or load main class CafeShopManagmentSystem
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CafeShopManagmentSystem

Comment: This may be related to your project structure and class path. You can open a new issue and describe your procedure in detail. Also you can read [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) for reference to using javafx in vscode. Also Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)